# Let P be a linear orthogonal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider in this question 3-dimensional Euclidean space $E^3$ . We suppose that **(e, f , g)** is orthogonal basis in this space.
$$(a)$$ Let P be a linear orthogonal operator acting on $E^3$  such that its matrix in the basis **(e, f , g)** has the following appearance:
$$7P = $$
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & * & 6   \\
    -6 & -3 & 2 \\
    2 & -6 & *  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Find the entries of the matrix denoted by $*$.
Show that the operator $P$ preserves orientation. We know that due to Euler Theorem the linear operator $P$ considered here is a rotation operator. Find the axis and the angle of this rotation.

I started out by using the result $(Px, Py)=(x,y)$ i.e.,
$$0=(e_1,e_2)=(e^1_1,e^2_2)=(P(e_1),P(e_2))$$ and went on to prove the first two results but can't seem to be able to wrap my head around the third one.

Answer (score 1):

The axis is the eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $1$: it is the vector $v$ such that $P v = v$. This is a linear system of equations in the components of $v$, which will determine $v$ up to a factor.

For the angle: pick a vector $u$ perpendicular to the axis $v$, and find the angle from the dot product between $u$ and $P u$.